# Google Embed API custom title

Tags: google-maps

How can i tell the Google Embed API that i want to show a custom title instead of the coordinates i send as the q parameter?

```
<iframe width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=321&q=37.4218,-122.0840&zoom=18&maptype=satellite">
</iframe>
```

This documentation is very limited and i believe there must be more options available:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Answer (score -1):

Add the title in parentheses like so:

```
<iframe width="400" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=321&q=37.4218,-122.0840+(My%20Business%20Name)&zoom=18&maptype=satellite">
```

Comment: Not sure if they changed things (as Google is wont to do), but it worked for me on the site I was working on at the time.

Comment: So, going back to the code I'm actually using in production, here's what it is — replace both instances of [$string]:

`<iframe class="mapsframe" width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=[$urlencoedstringhere]+([$urlencodedcustomnamehere])&key=xxxxxx"></iframe>`